# Car / bus 12 volt wifi router external storage

Tags: wifi, router, portable, mobile-workstation

Our family does long distance car travel 2 or 3 times a year.  I have young kids and I load up movies and tv shows spread across all tablet and phone devices.  What I'd prefer do is run a wifi router in the car that has attached storage.  The router can also support 3/4G network.

I found http://en.four-faith.com/f3a36h-mediawifioperating-marketingrouter.html but they seem to be the manufacturer intended to be used by wholesalers.

Does anyone know where I can buy such gear retail? I live in Australia.  I've searched and searched but can't find a thing.

Alternatively, can what suggestions are there to enable my requirements?

Comment: I'm putting my solution here, not as an answer, because I don't think your best solution lies in a single router. You can still upvote this comment if you like it. My solution is to have you buy a standard car DC to AC inverter if your car doesn't have one built in, then plug a standard retail wireless router with USB filehosting into that, and then configure your router to use its wifi to get the external connection - use OpenWRT on it if necessary - a 4G hotpot modem or one of your 4G-connected phones in tethering mode. I do this in my van and it is the cheapest way I've found to do it.

Comment: Sounds great Adam.  I've modified the question so that you can make your comment an answer.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your best solution lies in a single router. My solution is to have you buy a standard car DC to AC inverter if your car doesn't have one built in, then plug a standard retail wireless router with USB filehosting into that, and then configure your router to use its wifi to get the external connection - use OpenWRT on it if necessary - a 4G hotpot modem or one of your 4G-connected phones in tethering mode. I do this in my van and it is the cheapest way I've found to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I chatted with rep from four-faith.com and they said I can buy from them. At worst I can enter into another chat to make the purchase happen. The model http://en.four-faith.com/f3a36h-mediawifioperating-marketingrouter.html seems best for my needs:

- 9 to 36 Volts DC
- 128GB SSD installed
- 3G / 4G
- IEEE 802.11b/g/n

---

Update:

Price - US$506 shipped.  If I was going to be travelling often then I wouldn't mind paying this.  For 2 or 3 times a year it is a bit too much.

---

Update:

They also have a model with 32G TF card instead of 128Gb SSD.  It is US$370 shipped.

Comment: This is going to be extremely expensive because it is plainly designed for an industrial application, not retail.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this product: https://www.fourfaith.com/f3436h-vehicle-wifioperatingrouter.html? I have bought this product and it is of very good quality.